# On a home screen widget with a StackView with 3 buttons the widget item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, widget

I have a widget layout with a StackView. In the widget item i have three buttons. The question is: how can i trigger 3 different events (one for each button).

**widget_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_round_corners"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bk_text_view"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="My Contacts"
        android:textColor="@color/Azure"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_title_size" />

    <StackView
        android:id="@+id/stack_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:loopViews="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_item_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/empty_view_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and

**widget_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_item_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_sem_foto"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWidgetNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#77000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txtWidgetSize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn_chamada"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_green"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn_mensagem"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn_email"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_red"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

on the **WidgetService.java**

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

    byte[] img = mContactos.get(position).getFoto();
    Bitmap theImage = null;
    try {
        theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_item, Utils.getResizedBitmap(theImage, 400, 400));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "-----------------------> Image Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_item, R.drawable.icon_sem_foto);
    }
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txtWidgetNome, mContactos.get(position).getNome());

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION, position);
    extras.putInt(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM_ID, mContactos.get(position).getId());
    extras.putString(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM_NAME, mContactos.get(position).getNome());
    extras.putString(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM_TELEFONE, mContactos.get(position).getTelefone());
    extras.putString(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM_EMAIL, mContactos.get(position).getEmail());

    Intent fillInItemIntent = new Intent();
    fillInItemIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInItemIntent);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.imgbtn_chamada, fillInItemIntent);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.imgbtn_mensagem, fillInItemIntent);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.imgbtn_email, fillInItemIntent);

    return rv;
}
```

and on **WidgetProvider.java**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "-----------------------------> onReceive");
    Log.i(TAG, "-----------------------------> onReceive Action = " + intent.getAction().toString());

    //AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case ACTION_TOAST:
        case ACTION_CALL:
            //int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            //                                     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            //int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION, 0);
            //int id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_ID, 0);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Call to: " + intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_NAME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MakeChamada(context, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_TELEFONE));
            break;
        case ACTION_SMS:
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS to: " + intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_NAME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MakeSMS(context, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_TELEFONE));
            break;
        case ACTION_EMAIL:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Send email to: " + intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_NAME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MakeEmail(context, intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_EMAIL));
            break;
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.i(TAG, "-----------------------------> onUpdate");
    // update each of the widgets with the remote adapter
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

        //Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
        //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

        //intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        //rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stack_view, intent);

        //rv.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);

        int groupId = WidgetConfiguration.loadGroupIdPref(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
        CreatePendingIntents(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i], groupId);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

public static void CreatePendingIntents(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, int groupId) {

    ClassWidgets groupWidget;
    DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    groupWidget = db.getwidget(groupId);
    db.close();

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.stack_view, SetContactList(context, appWidgetId, groupId));

    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtTitle, groupWidget.getDescricao());

    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, SetToastBroadcastToast(context, appWidgetId));
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.imgbtn_mensagem, SetMenssagemBroadCastToast(context, appWidgetId)); //<------

    //RemoteViews remoteViewsIn = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_chamada, GetPendingChamadasIntent(context));
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_mensagem, GetPendingMensagemIntent(context));
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_email, GetPendingEmailIntent(context));
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_chamada, SetChamadaBroadCastToast(context, appWidgetId));
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_mensagem, SetMensagemBroadCastToast(context, appWidgetId));
    //remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_email, SetEmailBroadCastToast(context, appWidgetId));

    //remoteViews.addView(R.id.stack_view, remoteViewsIn);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}

private static PendingIntent SetToastBroadcastToast(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
    toastIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.ACTION_TOAST);
    toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return toastPendingIntent;
}

private static PendingIntent SetMenssagemBroadCastToast(Context context, int appWidgetId) {  // <----
    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
    toastIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.ACTION_SMS);
    toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return toastPendingIntent;
}

//******************************************************************************************
// Handle Contact List
private static Intent SetContactList(Context context, int appWidgetId, int groupId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.putExtra(GROUP_ID, groupId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    return intent;
}

//******************************************************************************************
// Handle Chamadas
private static PendingIntent GetPendingChamadasIntent(Context context) {
    Intent btnChamadasIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    btnChamadasIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 964770078));
    PendingIntent pendingIntentChamadas = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, btnChamadasIntent, 0);
    return pendingIntentChamadas;
}

private static PendingIntent SetChamadaBroadCastToast(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent chamadaIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
    chamadaIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.ACTION_CALL);
    chamadaIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent chamadaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, chamadaIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return chamadaPendingIntent;
}

private void MakeChamada(Context context, String telefone) {
    Intent btnChamadasIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    btnChamadasIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + telefone));
    context.startActivity(btnChamadasIntent);
}

//******************************************************************************************
// Handle Mensagens
private static PendingIntent GetPendingMensagemIntent(Context context) {
    Intent btnMensagemIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    btnMensagemIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    btnMensagemIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    btnMensagemIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + 964770078));
    btnMensagemIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Olá!");
    PendingIntent pendingMensagemIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, btnMensagemIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingMensagemIntent;
}

private static PendingIntent SetMensagemBroadCastToast(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent mensagemIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
    mensagemIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.ACTION_SMS);
    mensagemIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent mensagemPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mensagemIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mensagemPendingIntent;
}

private void MakeSMS(Context context, String telefone) {
    Intent btnMensagemIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    btnMensagemIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    btnMensagemIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    btnMensagemIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + telefone));
    btnMensagemIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Olá!");
    context.startActivity(btnMensagemIntent);
}

//******************************************************************************************
// Handle Email
private static PendingIntent GetPendingEmailIntent(Context context) {
    Intent btnEmailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    btnEmailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "emailText");
    PendingIntent pendingEmailIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, btnEmailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingEmailIntent;
}

private static PendingIntent SetEmailBroadCastToast(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
    emailIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.ACTION_EMAIL);
    emailIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent emailPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, emailIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return emailPendingIntent;
}

private void MakeEmail(Context context, String email) {
    Intent btnEmailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    btnEmailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    btnEmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "emailText");
    context.startActivity(btnEmailIntent);
}
```

On my code every click triggers only de ACTION_TOAST!
I alredy tried same solutions (also on code) without result!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: put break; after ACTION_TOAST

Comment: I want same action for ACTION_TOAST and ACTION_CALL. So no break!

Comment: All your buttons have *the same* intent object, so whatever the `RemoteViews` class does to intent on one button happens to all other buttons which use the same Intent. In your particular case, it just so happened that all buttons end up with intent for `ACTION_TOAST`. I bet if you reorder some method calls, you'll end up with different actions on each button (but still the same). To fix, you should use **different** intent objects.

Comment: You may have some reason... but it is more than that! The ACTION_TOAST is aplied to stack_view and it reacts to that. I have walready tried change those intents with no luke. What i can't do is to create some reaction to the image buttons within widget_item.

Answer (score 0):

So Basically you have to do 2 things to add onClick behavior to a button in StackView/ListView in Android App Widget.

In the getViewAt function of StackRemoteViewsFactory which implements RemoteViewService.RemoteServiceFactory, add a setOnClickFillingIntent() for the id you want to add function. eg.

```
 RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget__fan);
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putInt(TestWidget.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
 Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
 fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
 rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.fan_status, fillInIntent); // id of button you want to add a onClick function to.
```

In your onUpdate function of WidgetProvider class which extends AppWidgetProvider, add a setPendingIntentTemplate(). eg.

```
 Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
 toastIntent.setAction(TestWidget.act1);
 toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
 PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.lview, toastPendingIntent);
```

Now, the action has been set for that particular button (R.id.fan_status in my case). You can add its functionalities in onRecieve() function. eg.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
    if (intent.getAction().equals(act1)) {
       // Add your functionalities
    }
}
```